# Installing ZFS?

Tags: ubuntu-core

is it possible to install ZFS to ubuntu core in the current 15.04 release?

I'm working on a pet project using docker to deploy a Plex + Couchpotato server to substitute FreeNas; Ubuntu Core seems ideal for the Job, except I currently have all my storage in ZFS.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Dardake, The setup instructions are for an older build of Ubuntu Core 15.04 which is deprecated. Please find the latest dev images for Ubuntu Core 16 [here](https://people.canonical.com/~mvo/all-snaps/16/all-snaps-pc.img.xz) and follow the same steps for installation.

Comment: I successfully created a new USB for Ubuntu Core 16. But I'm getting stucked during configuration at the store email. I'm using the same email as in http://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com could you point me in the right direction? Thanks

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it was the Ubuntu One user. Thanks

Comment: Ok. I found the instructions to install classic, as your previous comment https://github.com/snapcore/classic-snap It worked! After an `apt update`I was able to install `zfs` and now I'm working to get my complete setup running. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are the kernel pieces in place already? If so it would not be difficult to snap up the userspace pieces.

Answer (score 0):

From [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Reference/ZFS):

> **ZFS**
>
> ZFS support was added to Ubuntu Wily 15.10 as a technology preview and
>   comes fully supported in Ubuntu Xenial 16.04. Note that ZFS is only
>   supported on 64 bit architectures. Also note that ZFS is only
>   supported for data storage, not the root filesystem.
>
> To install ZFS, use:
>
> `sudo apt install zfsutils-linux`

Comment: Except that in Ubuntu Core there's no `apt get` available. It's all about the snaps

Comment: @Darkade, what platform are you doing this on? If its a standard off the shelf x86/rpi device, you can migrate to our latest Ubuntu Core 16 dev images where you can install classic shell and be able to apt-get install whatever you like.

Comment: @ManikTaneja I'm installing directly to an intel device, so I used the NUC setup instructions and installed to an USB drive https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/start/intel-nuc/

Comment: But ZFS is only supported on 64 bits arch...

Comment: @ThiagoRiderAugusto my CPU is 64bit and as far as I understand Ubuntu core is 64 bits for intel. At least that what reads in the get started. Also when I `(amd64)ubuntu@localhost:~$ arch` it returns `x86_64 `  https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/start/